# Como ligar uma struct na outra?

Tags: c, struct

Iniciei na programação em C há pouco tempo e estou com uma dúvida a respeito de `structs`, eu gostaria de saber se é possível ligar duas `structs` para simular um relacionamento entre tabelas, por exemplo `struct categoria`:

```
struct categoria
{
    int codigo_categoria;
    char descricao_categoria[20];
};
```

Relacionada com `struct produto`:

```
struct produto
{
    char nome[30];
    int codigo_ligacao_categoria;
};
```

Existe uma maneira de ligar o membro `codigo_categoria` da `struct categoria` com o membro `codigo_ligacao_categoria` da `struct produto`?

Comment: Sim, mas a forma de fazer isto, depende do objetivo que precisa ser alcançado. Tem algum código que está usando? Isto ajudaria entender a intenção.

Comment: O objetivo é informar a categoria no produto através do código dela, para descobrir se existe uma categoria já cadastrada quando o usuário informar o código da categoria quando estiver cadastrando um produto. O código que eu quero implementar nesta ligação entre as structs ainda não esta pronto.

Comment: Porque basicamente o que você mostrou já está fazendo isto. Não sei se existe alguma dúvida real. Neste caso o membro `codigo_ligacao_categoria` será preenchido com o `codigo_categoria` da variável de uma estrutura específica.

Comment: É que eu queria garantir que os valores do campo codigo_categoria não sofram mudança caso ja exista uma categoria, seria como uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: Dá para fazer mas dá trabalho, é díficil ajudar do zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C você tanto pode ter uma struct de outro tipo "embutida" na sua struct original, como pode usar "ponteiros" - um otneiro é uma referência para outra estrutura na memória - 
e na prática, comparando com bancos relacionais, funciona como um "id" de outra tabela - só que em vez de um número de ID (que em geral nos viciamos em ver sequencialmente, números bonitinhos ID1, Id 2, id 3), temos um endereço de memória. (que nas arquiteturas modernas é um número de 64bit "#muitolouco") .

Vou colocar os dois exemplos:

```
struct categoria
{
    int codigo_categoria;
    char descricao_categoria[20];
};

struct produto
{
    char nome[30];
    struct categoria esta_categoria;
};
```

Dessa forma, você tem uma categoria completa, independente de qualquer outra instância dos mesmos dados, dentro do seu produto. É mais simples, por que você não precisa se preocupar com a lógica de ponteiros, etc -- se voce cria uma categoria, pode usar um simples sinal de "=" para atribuir uma cópia de sua categoria à categoria dentro de um produto:

```
struct produto meu_produto;
struct categoria minha_categoria;
...
meu_produto.esta_categoria = minha_categoria;
printf("Descrição da categoria: %s\n", meu_produto.esta_categoria.descricao);
```

Isso vai copiar todos os campos da struct categoria para outra struct dentro do produto.

Em aplicações reais, em geral não é o desejado - como você coloca, o interessante é ter uma referência para outra categoria - que pode estar num array, ou outra estrutura de dados - nesse caso, a sintaxe fica:

```
struct categoria
{
    int codigo_categoria;
    char descricao_categoria[20];
};

struct produto
{
    char nome[30];
    struct categoria *esta_categoria;
};

...
meu_produto.esta_categoria = &minha_categoria;
printf("Descrição da categoria: %s\n", meu_produto.esta_categoria->descricao);
```

Nesse caso, o que fica na struct produto é uma *referência* para o conteúdo da outra struct (exatamente como no relacionamento SQL). Se a struct de categoria original for alterada, a alteração poderá ser vista acessando a categoria através do produto.

No entando há uma diferença fundamental para um relacionamento SQL - as referências para estruturas com ponteiros são válidas apenas para o processo que está em execução, carregado em memória. Numa referência em banco de dados, se você desligar tudo, ligar de novo, ao carregar o produto, vai ter um categoria_id que ainda vai ser válido na tabela de categorias.

No programa em C, supondo-se que você crie ou use um mecânismo para persistir os dados brutos das structs entre uma execução e outra do programa, ao carregar os dados de uma struct "produto" o ponteiro que ela tem para a categoria é inválido, e para todos os efeitos, aponta para uma região aleatória da memória. Então, para cada struct que referêncie outras, num sistema que precise persistir dados - seja em banco, em arquivo, na rede, etc...você tem que criar de forma associada àquela struct funções para anexar as structs relacionadas (e também para liberar a memória de structs relacionadas, quando a struct principal for desalocada) -  para este exemplo, você poderia ter uma:

```
struct categoria
{
    int codigo_categoria;
    char descricao_categoria[20];
    int referencias=0;
};

void produto_adiciona_categoria(struct produto *este_produto, struct categoria *esta_categoria) {
    *produto->esta_categoria = esta_categoria;
    esta_categoria->referencias += 1;
}

void produto_remove_categoria(struct produto *este_produto) {
    struct categoria *tmp = este_produto->categoria;
    este_produto->categoria=NULL;
    if (--(tmp->referencias) <= 0) {
        free(tmp)
    }
}
```

Perceba que mesmo numa aplicação pequena, para evitar problemas de vazamento de memória, você teria que começar a contar quantas referências existem para cada estrutura na memória - e criar funões para criar e destruir cada tipo de estrutura baseadas na contagem de referências -- o gerenciamento disso escala bem rápido - e quando vocẽ percebe está criando um sistema de orientação a objetos para fazer seu programa (e portanto, reinventando a roda).

Eu termino com duas sugestões: pare qualquer tentativa de desenvolver seu código para entender "ponteiros" em C  -eles são lógicos, e é relativamente fácil entender os seus mecanismos, se estivermos focados nisso - mas se for deixar entrar aos poucos, e "bom, no exemplo tem esse *, então vou colocar um * aqui e ver se funciona" - a coisa fica complicada, cansativa, e vai gerar sentimentos aversivos.

A outra recomendação: 
A não ser que você esteja fazendo isso para aprender C como objetivo final, e não para ter um programa funcional, eu recomendo usar uma linguagem de mais alto nível para esse tipo de código.
EM linguagens dinâmicas como Python, Javascript ou Ruby, associar dados como você quer, que é feito com "objetos" nessas linguagens, em vez das structs do C é dezenas de vezes mais simples - ainda mais para quem está começando.

Comment: Muito obrigada @jsbueno :-); você me ajudou muito e eu entendi claramente sua explicação. Quanto ao objetivo final desse programa, eu tenho que aprender a usar a linguagem C devido a metodologia de ensino da Faculdade.

Comment: Ok - então lembre-se do conselho de entender direitinho o que são ponteiros. Não hesite em fazer mais perguntas para entender isso. E se quiser, me passe em pvt um contato do coordenador(a) do seu curso. (meu e-mail está no perfil) - e vamos bater um papo sobre essa história de aprender C antes de outras linguagens. (C é importante, mas hoje em dia tem nichos e problemas em que ela é melhor - e primeira linguagem de programação não é um deles).